# What determines whether or not an attribute can be used as a configurable option in a configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product

I've been doing a little digging in the database and noticed `is_configurable` is oftentimes set to `1` despite not being used to configure a configurable product (such as `custom_design_from`). I know this is column is responsible for this, however, because the option switches to its off state when I change the value for e.g. `color`. Is there something I'm missing? How does Magento determine this?